# ETL / Replication from Azure SQL Database to on-premises SQL Server data warehouse

Tags: sql-server, azure, etl

I'm trying to build daily ETL process from Azure SQL Database to on-premises SQL Server data warehouse.

I have experience in ETL between on-premises SQL Servers but when it comes to Azure I'm not sure the best practise. I did some researches and got the options on ETL and ADP.

Would anyone here have similar experience before, could shed me some lights? Any comment, example or  tutorial are much appreciated.

Comment: It's just another sql server that happens to end in `.database.windows.net`, and you can't use windows authentication. There's really nothing that different. What specific issue are you having? Are you going to run your ETL in Azure (probably use ADF) or on-premises?

Comment: Thanks @Nick.McDermaid, think that's what I need to know. When I did google there are just too many fancy things around Azure, and you pointed out the key - can't use windows auth. Glad I'm on the right track.

Comment: Hi @ydoow, is my answer helpful for you?

Comment: @LeonYue, basically I'm able to achieve what I need from Nick's suggestion. Yet your answer is helpful too, gave me some possible alternatives, just I didn't have chance to verify. Thanks heaps.

Comment: @ydoow you're welcome. You can do some research. If it's helpful,  hope you can accept it as answer. This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways can help you build daily ETL process from Azure SQL Database to on-premises SQL Server data warehouse.

I would suggest you think about [Azure Data Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/introduction) or Azure SQL database [Data Sync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/sql-data-sync-data-sql-server-sql-database).

Data Factory can help you build a pipeline to copy the data between Azure SQL database and On-premise SQL Server. You could create a time trigger to [trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-pipeline-execution-triggers#trigger-execution) the copy daily. Ref these documents:

1. [Copy and transform data in Azure SQL Database by using Azure Data
   Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-sql-database)
2. [Copy data to and from SQL Server by using Azure Data Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-sql-server)

Data Sync is a feature of Azure SQL database, you can sync the data between SQL database and on-premise SQL Server automatically. I think that's the easiest and cheapest way which can achieve your request in some way. Just note the [requirements and limitations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/sql-data-sync-data-sql-server-sql-database#sync-req-lim).

And like @Nick said, Azure SQL database doesn't support windows authentication, please use SQL authentication or AD.

HTH.